# Print same text several time to one page

Tags: pdf, printing, print-to-pdf, ubuntu-12.04

I have a `odt`(or `pdf`, or `ps`) file. [Really I have `odt`, but I can easily convert it], it consist of 1 page.

No I want to print it to another `pdf` 4 times to 1 page. There is an option `pages per side`, so If I copy-paste 4 times my document and set this option to 4 I'll have my expected result.

But I want to do it without copy-paste because it's quite annoying to copy-and-paste before each printing.

Is it simpler way?

Comment: Do you want to increase the paper size or scale down the page?

Comment: @Marco I want to scale down, as 4 pages per side usually do, but with same pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tool [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page). Either you install it with your package manager (eg. from TeXLive) or on a per-user base: [Installation](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone)

Then you create a file `fourup.tex` with the following content:

```
\setuppapersize     [A6] [A4]
\setuppagenumbering [location=]
\setupbackgrounds   [page]
\setuplayout        [nx=2, ny=2]

\starttext
\doifdocumentargumentelse{inputfile}{%
  \copypages [\getdocumentargument{inputfile}] [scale=500]}{Missing input file}
\stoptext
```

Then you can call ConTeXt: `context --inputfile=myfile --result=result.pdf fourup`.
`myfile` is the original file without PDF extension. The result is a file `result.pdf` with four pages copied on one.

Comment: thanks, it works great, but what should I change to print it 9 times?

Comment: Change A6 to A7 and nx and ny to 3, instead of two. Then change the scale to something like 300.